# Updating to tensorflow 2.0 : concept of epoch in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was previously using the Estimator API in tensorflow and using "max_steps" which was the number of batches seen during training.
My dataset is completely synthetic and infinite, a completely new batch of images is generated on the fly each time.
The new Keras API uses the concept of "epochs" which corresponds to an entire pass through a dataset. How do I set "steps_per_epoch" and "initial_Epoch" and "epochs" in the keras "fit" function so that it makes sense in my case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is also a parameter with this exact name, `steps_per_epoch`, in `model.fit()` function, which lets you define the number of steps you want to have that is equal to an epoch. Let's say you want to have `steps_per_epoch=4` meaning `4x8 = 32`, when batch size is `8`. 32 meaning here that the model will see 32 samples from the dataset now.

There is also `initial_epoch` argument which functions exactly as the name says.

`epochs` also exists in `.fit()` will take total number of epochs you want. SO lets say wyou want to train if for 10 epochs, then for each epoch the model will see 32 image samples and after 10th epoch it will `10x32= 320`

These all functions are defined [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#arguments_6).

Answer (score -1):

Below are common definitions that are necessary to know and understand to correctly utilize Keras:

---

1. Sample: one element of a dataset.
2. Batch: a set of N samples.
3. epochs：Number of times all samples were trained.
4. steps_per_epoch：Steps here equal to splited batches_number. In
   addition, it is worth mentioning that the batch size !=
   batches_number，batch size is traning sample_number of one step.

Answer your additional comments：

---

The keras model does not care about the sample length. For example, a model can receive an input tensor of similar (None, w, h, c) shape. The None of the 0-axis is the question of #samples you care about, but you don't need to care.

**So no need to specify sample size for Input tensor in keras.**

In addition, the sample data collection process can be dynamic, but the samples used for analysis are always fixed. You need to divide the development set and test set. The newly collected samples should be added to the development set and test set in a certain period of time, such as a week or a month, and need to ensure that the collected samples meet the same distribution.

Read about [def Input](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/input_layer.py#L114) may help you.

Comment: Ok but I don't have a number for "all samples" in my case. There is no end to this dataset.

Comment: Training time is finit. Thus, even if your dataset Is generated on the fly you have to decide how many batches to include in an epoch and how many epoch to include in your training. How big these two numbers are it's up to you, your patience and your computing power.